# Irregular plot size in Mathematica 13

Tags: bugs, front-end, version-13

I have just upgraded to Mathematica 13.0.1 today, and when I went to open my notebooks, I noticed something very strange regarding my plots. They seemed to be irregularly sized, with large empty spaces taking up "image size". The changes were not consistent from one plot to the other, and one of them even appeared to be unchanged! Here are 3 examples (the third one has a lot of empty vertical space):

[image: Notice the large empty space to the left of the vertical axis]

[image: In this one, empty space was added to the right]

[image: In this one, a lot of empty space was added everywhere, so much so that the resulting plot is barely visible]

This happened to both new ones I tried to plot (with the regular set of options I've been using since version 10), but also to the ones I had already previously plotted and printed to the screen with Show, but not yet replotted! They were like this as I opened the notebook - before I ran anything at all. This seems like a good indication that this is a FrontEnd issue, but I have no idea how to fix it. Re-running the plots returned the exact same irregularity. Adding options to the plots like AspectRatio or changing ImageSize did nothing. Copying the entire contents of the notebook to a new one and reevaluating everything did nothing. I deleted all the configuration files, but the irregularity persists.

Here is an example listing the options I specify for these plots:

```
sizeOfFont=16;
sizeOfImage=600;
ListPlot[dataNonNucNu,
  Joined -> True,
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {
        Style["Age (Myears)", FontSize -> sizeOfFont],
    Style["log L [\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(L\), \(\[CircleDot]\)]\)]", 
     FontSize -> sizeOfFont, FontColor -> Black]
        },
  PlotStyle -> {modelCheckColor, Dashed},
  FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> sizeOfFont],
  FrameTicks -> newTicks,
  LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[
    {
     Style["Thermal \[Nu]", FontSize -> sizeOfFont]
     },
    {0.65, 0.15}
    ],
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic},
  ImageSize -> sizeOfImage
  ];
```

Finally, I managed to track down the source of the problem to the `PlotTheme -> "Scientific"` option. If I remove it, the plots go back to their appointed size. Trying other PlotThemes didn't reveal any problems, and trying the Scientific Plot Theme in a new notebook, with these exact options and a simpler dataset, worked just fine.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: This seems strange indeed. It would be worthwhile to preserve this notebook with errors present & submit it to WRI’s tech support!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. My only fear is that they will be unable to replicate this bug without the full dataset I used (which is quite extensive). I tried the exact same plotting options with different data and the plot worked normally.
But even this does not appear to work (or not work) consistently. Several of my version 12 notebooks with much simpler datasets reveal similar problems. I'm not even quite sure how I'd go about documenting this so that it could be of use to the suport team.